# PHP: Proxy another url

Tags: php, proxy, curl

I have a `mod_rewrite` rule that will send any subdomain requests to a php script which should proxy those requests to another host (internal proxy, not 302).

I'm close, in that my script works with web browsers, but curl seems not like it:

```
curl: (56) Received problem 2 in the chunky parser
```

Here is my mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/proxy.php?__path=%1 [QSA,L]
```

And my `proxy.php`

```
<?php

$name = $_GET['__path'];
unset($_GET['__path']);
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$url = "http://$name.internal.example.com$path";
$ch = curl_init($url);
$headers = array();
foreach (apache_request_headers() as $key => $value) {
    $headers[] = "$key: $value";
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);  

$data = curl_exec($ch);

list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
$headers = explode("\r\n", $headers);
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    header($header);
}
die($body);
```

Any reason why curl doesn't like this but browsers are ok with it?

**EDIT:** It seems if I don't send the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header, everything is ok (since I'm proxying the full request, chunking isn't possible). So a follow up question: Can I act as a true middleman and send the data as I get it over the socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able send data over the network as you get it.  But I suspect your problem may stem from persistent http connections.  HTTP 1.0 will break the connection after the request,  in your code you are creating a new CURL handle for each request,  which is more like HTTP/1.0 instead of the default HTTP/1.1

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
```

You may still have problems with the application layer because CURL isn't meant to act as a proxy like this.  Another approach would be to modify an existing [PHP HTTP Client](http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/index.php) and make sure that the forwarded requests are close enough for your needs.

No matter what approach you use, I highly recommend using WireShark for debugging.  You can then dump 2 http requests and then use something like [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) to pick out the differences.